# ABP - MVC How to develop a own custom theme

Tags: themes, abp

I am looking for days for a howto article how to implement an own theme for abp mvc.
Is there any info? I only found this link
https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/themes/lepton-x/index. Is there any more detailed article to implement this. I want to have the possibility to switch between the normal theme and a customer theme in the ui.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article on the ABP Community website that explains how to create a new UI theme by copying the Basic Theme for MVC UI 1. The article provides a step-by-step guide on how to create a new solution, copy the Basic Theme project into the solution, remove the Basic Theme NuGet package in the Web project, build the Basic Theme project, fix errors, reference the newly added local Basic Theme project in the Web project, and make changes in the Basic Theme project to see it in action 1.

You can also find more information about theming in ABP’s documentation center 23. The easiest way to create a new theme is by adding the Basic Theme Source Code module with source codes and customizing it

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Theming